# How to left-align the sentence after the sign in this Beamer TeX?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

In this TeX, I want "is" in the first line aligned with "this" in the second line. How that is possible?

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome}


\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

\section{Descriptive Outline 1}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}

 \faQuestionCircle \vspace{3mm} Is there a question about the this topic that has not been answerd nowhere yet in this text ?

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see no ‘it’ in whatever line.

Comment: Sorry, It is "is". corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itemize` environment like the follows

```
\documentclass[
aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome}


\usetheme{Darmstadt}        


\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont}



\begin{document}


\section{Descriptive Outline 1}

\subsection{Outline}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Outline}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[\faQuestionCircle] Is there a question about the this topic that has not been answerd nowhere yet in this text ?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{Descriptive Outline 1}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}

 \faQuestionCircle\quad \vspace{3mm}\parbox[t]{5in}
 { Is there a question about this topic that has not been answered nowhere yet in this text ?}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I know why this answer was downvoted?